# C# excel chart line weight

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

I am currently working with a .NET excel interupt and have run into an issue. When I make a chart in excel, the series line weights are automatically set to 2.5. I created a solution that loops through all of the series and change the weighting to 1. However, I was wondering if there is someway to select all the series at once and change the line weight of every series at once. 
This is what I have currently:

```
     foreach (Series series in c.SeriesCollection())
        {
            series.Format.Line.Weight = 1;
        }
```

Comment: Nope. You need to loop through the series collection.

Comment: That is really unfortunate.

Comment: It's not really such a big deal, is it?

Comment: It is a big deal when you are dealling with at least 30 graphs and 200 series per graph

Comment: Not really, if you can just write a nested loop and let it run.